# In SQL can I Perform Logic on Multiple Columns, which are SELECT Statements?

Tags: sql

I am trying to accomplish the following, and I am not sure if it is possible. I have a `SELECT` Statement that contains an inner `SELECT` for two of the table columns like so:

```
SELECT 
col1,
col2,

   (SELECT SUM(col1)
    FROM table2)
    AS FirstResultToAdd,

   (SELECT SUM(col2)
    FROM table3)
    AS SecondResultToAdd,

FROM Table1
```

So my question is: Is it possible to perform a calculation, such as doing a `SUM` of "FirstResultToAdd" and "SecondResultToAdd, and returning that as a single column result on "Table1"? Also to keep in mind, I have excluded any joins of the tables to keep the example simple.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are using.  Also sample data and desired results would help clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, but each subquery must return a scalar value,  Is there a correlation between the Table1 outer query and the subqueries?  If not, you will get the same value in each row.

Comment: There are joins occurring from Table1, to Table2 and Table3, and also each subquery will join to other tables as well. Right now I have each Subquery returning a single result, and to be more specific, the columns in the subquery is returning a `SUM` of values as a single column. After getting these single values, the question is how would I perform logic on both of these results, and apply it to Table1 as a column result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to perform some logic on the result of `Sub-query`

To add the two `sub-query` result

```
SELECT col1, 
       col2,

      (SELECT col1 
       FROM table2)   
       AS FirstResultToAdd, 

      (SELECT col2 
       FROM table3)   
       AS SecondResultToAdd, 

      (SELECT col1 
       FROM table2) 
       + 
      (SELECT col2 
       FROM table3) 
       AS total 
       FROM table1
```

To make the query more readable you can make the original query as `Sub-Select` and perform the logic in `Outer query`

Answer (score 0):

just nest one more time...

```
select col1, col2, sum( FirstResultToAdd )
from (
SELECT 
col1,
col2,

   (SELECT col1
    FROM table2)
    AS FirstResultToAdd,

   (SELECT col2
    FROM table3)
    AS SecondResultToAdd,

FROM Table1
)
```

Comment: Thanks!, I am attempting this now

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Fixed Group By

Try this:

```
 Select     A.Col1,
            A.Col2,
           (B.Col3 + C.Col4)

From(
        (Select Col1,
                Col2
         From   [Table1]) A

        Inner join (Select  Sum(Col3) AS Col3
        From    [Table2]) B on 1 = 1

        Inner join (Select  Sum(Col4) AS Col4
        From    [Table3]) C on 1 = 1
     )
Group By  A.Col1,
          A.Col2,
          B.Col3,
          C.Col4
```